# Estoy buscando una función que me cuente los números pares e impares de una variable con varios números

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando en JavaScript y estoy intentando conseguir que me devuelva la cantidad de números pares e impares de una variable con varios números, he probado de varias maneras pero no lo consigo, la variable es esta: let numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: Se ve que no buscaste bien. Puedes usar un for para recorrer el arreglo y un contador que lleve la cuenta de cuántos pares e impares hay.

Comment: ¿de que maneras lo has probado?  Ponlas en la pregunta para que sea válida, sino parece que nos estes encomendando la tarea a nosotros y aqui no hacemos tareas (o no deberiamos, si te la hacen es porque tampoco saben como funciona este sitio), resolvemos dudas y errores.

Comment: Solo tienes que escribir en un buscador "obtener números pares javascript" y ya lo tienes.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].reduce( ( impares, actual )=> ( impares += actual % 2 ), 0)`  `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].reduce( ( pares, actual )=> ( pares += 1 - actual % 2 ), 0)` (  con calcular uno el otro sale del resto )

Answer (score 1):

Se sabe fácilmente si un número es par usando el [operador de "resto"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder), los pares siempre dan como resultado 0 si hacemos el resto de 2, por ejemlo:

```
console.log(16 % 2); // 0
console.log(8 % 2);  // 0
console.log(2 % 2);  // 0
```

Entonces si tienes una serie de números solo hay que recorrerlos y comprobar uno a uno:

```js
    // Obtener pares
    function getEvenNumbers(arrNumbers) // array
    {
        const output = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < arrNumbers.length; index++) {
            const number = arrNumbers[index];
            if (number % 2 === 0) {
                output.push(number);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
    // Obtener impares
    function getOddNumbers(arrNumbers) // array
    {
        const output = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < arrNumbers.length; index++) {
            const number = arrNumbers[index];
            if (number % 2 !== 0) {
                output.push(number);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    console.log('Pares: ', getEvenNumbers(numbers)); // Pares: [2, 4, 6]
    console.log('Impares: ', getOddNumbers(numbers)); // Impares: [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

> Editado

Para contar los números de cada tipo, obtienes el array respectivo
y mides su longitud, puedes hacerlo en base a las funciones anteriores.
Se usará la función `length`, consulta [como medir la longitud de un array con javascropt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

```js
    // Functions ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Obtener pares
    function getEvenNumbers(arrNumbers) // array
    {
        const output = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < arrNumbers.length; index++) {
            const number = arrNumbers[index];
            if (number % 2 === 0) {
                output.push(number);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
    // Obtener impares
    function getOddNumbers(arrNumbers) // array
    {
        const output = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < arrNumbers.length; index++) {
            const number = arrNumbers[index];
            if (number % 2 !== 0) {
                output.push(number);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
    function countEvenNumbers(arrNumbers) // int
    {
        return getEvenNumbers(arrNumbers).length;
    }
    function countOddNumbers(arrNumbers) // int
    {
        return getOddNumbers(arrNumbers).length;
    }

    // Run script //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    console.log('Pares: ', countEvenNumbers(numbers));  // Pares: 3
    console.log('Impares: ', countOddNumbers(numbers)); // Impares: 4
```

Si quieres que una unica función te devuelva ambos datos, puedes devolver
un objeto con la información y acceder a ella usando la notación de punto o array:

```js
    // Functions ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Obtener pares
    function getEvenNumbers(arrNumbers) // array
    {
        const output = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < arrNumbers.length; index++) {
            const number = arrNumbers[index];
            if (number % 2 === 0) {
                output.push(number);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
    // Obtener impares
    function getOddNumbers(arrNumbers) // array
    {
        const output = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < arrNumbers.length; index++) {
            const number = arrNumbers[index];
            if (number % 2 !== 0) {
                output.push(number);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
    function countEvenNumbers(arrNumbers) // int
    {
        return getEvenNumbers(arrNumbers).length;
    }
    function countOddNumbers(arrNumbers) // int
    {
        return getOddNumbers(arrNumbers).length;
    }
    function getEventAndOddNumbersAmounts(arrNumbers)
    {
        return {
            event_total: countEvenNumbers(arrNumbers),
            odd_total: countOddNumbers(arrNumbers),
        };
    }

    // Run script //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    const data = getEventAndOddNumbersAmounts(numbers);
    console.log('Pares: ', data.event_total); // Pares: 3
    console.log('Impares: ', data.odd_total); // Impares: 4
```

Mira aquí [como trabajar con objetos en javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#objetos_y_propiedades).